# In Python 3.6, how could a long running loop cause a variable to become undefined?

Tags: python, variables

**Short Version:**
I have a nested loop that, when it runs for a longer time than normal (2 hours),something causes a variable to become undefined only within that inner loop. the outer loop is able to use it without issue.

**Long Version:**
I have a Python 3.6 script running on a RHEL box which is extracting tables from a SQL server, 500,000 rows at a time, and writing them into a .csv file, which then gets processed into a different database.

I first make the connections to the source and target in a Class so that the session persists and is reused for each action. I have heartbeat queries that run to keep otherwise inactive sessions alive while I run loops. (not shown, but currently in outer loop only - that is soon to change)

The Framework is fairly straightforward...I read a list of source tables from a file into a dataframe. Then, the code is (Some code in the inner loop is removed, but the comment explaining what is happening is left in). :

```
for index, row in tables_to_load.iterrows():

    #try to load all new rows into target
    try: 
        table_name = tables_to_load['Source_Table'][index]
        pk = tables_to_load['pk'][index]
        odsstage_table_name = tables_to_load['ODSSTAGE_Table'][index]
        ods_table_name = tables_to_load['ODS_Table'][index]
        last_loaded_lsn = sf_ods.get_last_loaded_lsn(table_name)
        max_lsn = source.get_max_lsn(table_name)

        # Get the number of rows to load
        incr_count = source.get_incr_count(table_name, pk, last_loaded_lsn)
        total_process_rows = total_process_rows + incr_count

        #WORKS FINE EVERY TIME
        file.write("There are  " + str(incr_count) + " rows to be loaded for the table: " + table_name + "\n\n")

        # Set up your offset limits
        offset_iterator = 0 # Start at the 1st row of the increment
        
        fetch_count = 500000 # Increment by 500k rows. 
        
        if incr_count == 0: #only run if there are new rows to load to target
            status = "No Rows To Load"

        
        else: # If there are rows to load, proceed loading them to target
            try:
                inc_write_success = 1

                # Begin looping through the increment in source until offset_iterator > the number of rows in the increment
                while offset_iterator < incr_count:
                    sf_dw.heartbeat()

                    #ERROR OCCURS HERE
                    file.write(table_name + ": Loading the next " + str(fetch_count) + " rows starting at row " + str(offset_iterator + 1) + " out of " + str(incr_count) + " rows" + "\n")
                                                             
                    # Get the incremental dataframe starting at the offset_indicator row
                    #the df is the first object returned
                    #the list of columns in the original table is the third object returned
                    
                    # Write the dataframe to a compressed file at the temporary storage
                    # Move the file to target and COPY INTO the ODSSTAGE table in target
                    
                    
                    # Merge ODSSTAGE to ODS
                                            
                    # Update the offset_iterator to fetch the next increment of rows until you've reached the max_lsn
                    offset_iterator += fetch_count
                 
            except Exception as e:
                any_errors = True
                inc_write_success = 0
         # Update log_cdc table
            try:
                if inc_write_success == 1:
                    #WORKS FINE
                    sf_ods.update_last_loaded_lsn(table_name, max_lsn, status)
                else:
                    #WORKS FINE
                    file.write("Unable to Update Max_LSN for " + table_name + " due to increment failure. \n")
            except Exception as e:
                file.write(str(e) + "\n")

    except Exception as e:
        file.write(str(e) + "\n")
        inc_write_success = 0

    stop_table_load = datetime.datetime.now()
    load_table_time = stop_table_load - table_load_start
    
    #AGAIN WORKS FINE
    file.write("Finished loading " + table_name + ". Load Time: " + str(load_table_time) + "\n")
```

Problem: whenever the inner loop takes more than 4 hours to complete, The next 'for' instance seems to handle everything fine up until the first run of the inner loop, where I am greeted with "name 'table_name' is not defined". Based on what I can tell, it seems to be happening in the indicated spot where I am filling out some lines for a log file. There are lines in the log file that indicate that the table_name variable is functioning correctly both before and after the inner loop is called.

The variable is NOT defined as global...it is defined at try.

Should I create it as a global variable instead? Rename it in the inner loop?

I'm not permitted to post anything much more specific about the project.

Comment: The while loop above "ERROR OCCURS HERE" has an unintended or missing body. This may be related to the issue or just a copy-pasting error, but either way it makes it difficult to reason about what is intended.

Comment: @Brian Indentation error. I have corrected that part. I added the heartbeat query, which is the only thing that happens in the loop before the file.write. It seems to be where the variable error ocurrs. I should also mention that this only happens about once per month, as a process in the source introduces far more rows than normal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not convinced the program is failing where you suggest, at least looking at this snippet alone.

I'm guessing `table_name = tables_to_load['Source_Table'][index]` is actually failing. If that fails, `table_name` will never get defined; your code will jump to your outer `except` statement and do the file write with inc_write_success stuff. Then it will attempt to do the
`file.write("Finished loading " + table_name + ". Load Time: " + str(load_table_time) + "\n")` and fail there.

Providing the stack trace that shows where the error occurred can be helpful in these cases too.

Comment: Fair enough. What is strange, and the reason I thought it failed there, is that in the log file, all of the statements that say "WORKS HERE" are writing using that variable into the file. So if the current table name is "BusinessData", the file reads as such:  Began loading BusinessData at 2022-02-27 07:12:30.753630
Loading rows after last_loaded_lsn 0x0038C9D200047DB0000C though the max_lsn 0x0
There are  0 rows to be loaded for the table: BusinessData

name 'table_name' is not defined
Updating CDC Log Increment to Max_LSN = 0x0
Finished loading BusinessData. Load Time: 0:00:01.000899

Comment: I'm afraid proving the stack trace is difficult, as this error only occurs once per month in our production system, and is very hard to replicate in the non-prod environment without adding an additional 5--hour wait task in the middle. I'm going to add some better logging for the time being and see if I can engineer a way to recreate.

Comment: After some searching and better logging, you're right..it was failing when it was trying to provide the error.